# Sequelize: Unable to set reference to two different tables after migrations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to set reference from donorslist table to user table and requestblood table. Though the references columns(userid, requestbloodid) are getting added to the table, it is failing to insert the reference id 'requestbloodid' in the column and sets it to NULL.

I am using

- Nodejs
- mysql: 2.16.0 v
- sequelize: 4.37.10 v

user.js model file:

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const user = sequelize.define(
'user',
 {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  fullname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
    allowNull: false,       
  },
  gender: { type: DataTypes.CHAR(1), allowNull: false },
  latitude: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 15),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: { min: -90, max: 90 },
  },
  longitude: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 15),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: { min: -180, max: 180 },
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: true,
  },
  isglobalcontactshared: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    get() {
      return moment.utc(new Date(), 'DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a').format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a');
    },
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: null,
   },
 },

 {
   freezeTableName: true,
 }
);

user.associate = function(models) {
user.belongsTo(models.contactdetails, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'contactdetailid',
    allowNull: false,
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
  },
 });
};
 return user;
};
```

requestblood.js file:

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const requestblood = sequelize.define(
'requestblood',
 {
   id: {
     type: DataTypes.UUID,
     primaryKey: true,
     allowNull: false,
     defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  requestid: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  latitude: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 15),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: { min: -90, max: 90 },
  },
  longitude: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 15),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: { min: -180, max: 180 },
  },
  locality: { type: DataTypes.STRING(20), allowNull: false },
  city: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  bloodtype: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    isNumeric: true,
    validate: { min: 1, max: 9 },
  },
  duedate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    allowNull: false,
    get() {
      return moment.utc(this.getDataValue('duedate')).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
    },
  },
  unitsrequired: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, isNumeric: true },
  description: { type: DataTypes.STRING(500) },
  requeststateid: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    get() {
      return moment.utc(new Date(), 'DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a').format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a');
    },
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: null,
  },
},
{
  freezeTableName: true,
}
);

requestblood.associate = function(models) {
requestblood.belongsTo(models.contactdetails, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'contactdetailid',
    allowNull: false,
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
  },
 });
};

/* requestblood.associate = function(models) {
requestblood.hasMany(models.donorslist, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'requestbloodid',
    allowNull: false,
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
  },
});
}; */

return requestblood;
};
```

donorslist.js file

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const donorslist = sequelize.define(
 'donorslist',
 {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  fullname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  bloodgroup: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  contactnumber: { type: DataTypes.STRING(13), allowNull: true },
  willdonate: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
  hasdonated: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    get() {
      return moment.utc(new Date(), 'DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a').format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm a');
    },
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: null,
  },
},
{
  freezeTableName: true,
 }
);

donorslist.associate = function(models) {
 donorslist.belongsTo(models.requestblood, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'requestbloodid',
    allowNull: false,
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
  },
});
};

donorslist.associate = function(models) {
donorslist.belongsTo(models.user, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'userid',
    allowNull: false,
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
   },
  });
};

return donorslist;
};
```

When the below code is executed,

```
models.donorslist
.create({
  fullname,
  bloodgroup: bloodgrp,
  contactnumber: contnum,
  willdonate: req.body.willdonate,
  userid: usrid,
  requestbloodid: reqid,
  updatedAt: null,
 })
```

`
it returns the query as:

```
INSERT INTO `donorslist` (`id`,`fullname`,`bloodgroup`,`contactnumber`,`willdonate`,`hasdonated`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`userid`) VALUES ('687888be-4381-460f-af62-46365a16fb40','sunil',4,'+123456789',true,false,'2019-01-10 07:00:12','2019-01-10 07:00:12','b93cfd73-a6ea-4825-91ad-8ded37418ca7');
```

Note the missing requestbloodid column. It somehow skips the requestbloodid column. I am facing this issue, after performing migrations. This was working fine with sequelize.sync(). If i uncomment the below code in requestblood.js file, then the referenceid 'contactdetailid' of requestblood table is set as NULL. So, i am unable to make a reference of belongsTo and hasMany from these two tables.

```
requestblood.associate = function(models) {
requestblood.hasMany(models.donorslist, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'requestbloodid',
    allowNull: false,
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
  },
});
};
```

Comment: Finally, got a solution by updating donorslist.js file as below:                                          
                                                                                                        
         donorslist.associate = function(models) {
        donorslist.belongsTo(models.user, {
        foreignKey: 'userid',
        targetKey: 'id',
        });

       donorslist.belongsTo(models.requestblood, {
       foreignKey: 'requestbloodid',
       targetKey: 'id',
       });
       };